# Android studio firestore timestamp comparing to currentLocalTime

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

So I want is to get the value of Firestore timestamp and Local device currentTime, and display the different:

```
Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) document.getData().get("createdAt");
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
//I need the result value of (tsLong - timestamp seconds)
```

But I'm stuck at the value calculating, how is it possible to get the milliseconds of the timestamp to Long type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In firestore timestamp, we have an API getSeconds(). This API return time in second (**long** data type).

```
Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) document.getData().get("createdAt");
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
long result = tsLong - timestamp.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not perform the calculation yourself if there is a standard API available to do the same.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println(seconds);

        // Alternatively, using java.time API
        seconds = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
        System.out.println(seconds);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/JxknVl)

#### Coming back to your problem:

You can use [`DocumentSnapshot#getTimestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getTimestamp(java.lang.String)) to get the `Timestamp` from which you can get the seconds using [`Timestamp#getSeconds`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#getSeconds()).

Thus, you can do it like

```
long diff = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) - document.getTimestamp("createdAt").getSeconds();
```

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

Using [`Timestamp#todate`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#public-date-todate), you can convert `Timestamp` to `java.util.Date` which can be converted into `java.time.Instant` and then you can use `java.time.Duration` to find the difference in seconds as shown below:

```
long seconds = Duration.between(Instant.now(), document.getTimestamp("createdAt").toDate().toInstant()).toSeconds();
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) class contains a method called [getTimestamp(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getTimestamp(java.lang.String)). So a simpler way to get the difference would be:

```
Timestamp createdAt = document.getTimestamp("createdAt");
Long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
long difference = seconds - createdAt.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Hey Neko. Have you also tried my solution above?